# How to read jsonp data in express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, cordova, express

I'm trying to send data from phonegap to an express app. Here is my code:

Phonegap:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:3000/test",
        data: {"test":"this works!"},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('data successfully sent');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('there was an error');
        }
    });
```

Express:

```
    app.post('/ajax' , function (req , res){
    console.log(req.body)
    res.redirect('/test');
    });
```

Right now `req.body` is an empty object. I've included `express.bodyParser()` at the top of my stack, and have also tried `JSON.parse(req.body)` and `JSON.stringify(req.body)`, but neither have worked.

Can anybody think of something else to try? Do I need to do something different because it's jsonp?

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the first example (using jQuery)? JSONP and http post are not compatible. Try using http GET.

Comment: It's showing the success function so I thought it was working. Should the GET be in the ajax call, the express app, or both?

Comment: You're manually specifying the content as JSON, but the `.ajax` converts the data to a querystring, not a JSON object.  Try `JSON.stringify`ing the data.

Comment: Check this article out: http://alpheussoftware.com/?p=20  It's got a working example of PhoneGap and JSONP with jQuery.

Comment: I tried changing everything I could to GETs. Still getting the same thing, success function, 200 code, and empty object. @TimBrown is there a work around for that?

Comment: Just `JSON.stringify` the data object, or remove the explicit `contentType` and send it as a normal form.

Comment: @TimBrown no luck. I mentioned that JSON.stringify was not working. Thanks richb01 I'll check that out.

Comment: I meant stringify the ajax data, not the request body once it gets there.  Your current ajax looks to be sending form encoded data, but saying it's sending json, which is probably confusing express.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Sorry for the beginner questions, but where would I use JSON.stringify inside of ajax? In the data value?

Comment: I tried data: JSON.stringify({"test":"this works!"}), but still got the same empty object in express. :(

Comment: Have you tried removing the `contentType` and just sending normal form data?  Also, your `.ajax` call seems to point to `/test` while the express app is listening at `/ajax`.  If you are doing a redirect in there somewhere, that's your problem.  Redirects don't send the POST body.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. I looked and my /test was identical to /ajax except that it included res.jsonp(req.body). I'm not entirely sure how/why that's in there, but when I take it out the phonegap app fails to load, so it must be doing something. However, req.body still seems to be an empty object. I noticed that my data does show up in the console here: GET /test?callback=jQuery20306638738175388426_1397625461458&{%22test%22:%22this%20works!%22}&_=1397625461459 200. Really not sure what the res.jsonp is doing.

Comment: `req.body` is for POSTs.  If you're doing a get, the data will be in `req.query`.

Comment: req.query totally did the trick. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery:

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000/test?callback=?", 
    {"test":"this works!"},
    function(data){
        // data should be {foo: "bar"}
        // ... DO CODE
    }
);
```

The node:

```
app.get('/test' , function (req , res){
    // req.query should be {test: "this works!"}
    // ... DO CODE
    res.jsonp({foo: "bar"})
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like $.getJSON is a shorthand ajax request? If you don't mind me asking, what is the significance of the '?callback=?'? Why does that need to be included?

Also, is it supposed to be res.jsonp(req.query)? Why does res.jsonp enable the ajax call to work?

Comment: `.getJSON` is just short for exactly that: getting json (more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)).  The `callback=?` section changes the request from a normal json GET into a jsonp GET.  jsonp requests add a callback query parameter that the server wraps it's response in (example: a request with `callback=foo` means that the server would send back `foo(SERVER_DATA_HERE)`).  In this case, jquery replaces `callback=?` with the actual callback jquery expects, and the ? is just an easy placeholder.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. I wouldn't have been able to figure this out without your help!

Comment: No problem.  I remember getting confused about jsonp when I was first playing with it too.  It's pretty weird and is mostly just a hack so we can get json data from different domains, so it's not the cleanest or the simplest.